# Quarkus trouble with SQL Server (or any other database)

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am developing a Quarkus application, and now I'm trying to configure the database. First off, I have tried to configure MySQL, but I don't know why look like my application is not recognizing when I put dependencies manually in the `pom.xml`. So I have tried to do the `./mvnw quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions="{dependencies}"` and anyway do not work.

Then I have tried to connect to a SQL Server because I am working on a similar application and I have the configuration easily to access, but the same error is being throw with `mvn clean install`:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.445 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-22T11:46:02-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.1.3.Final:build (default) on project weather-music-recommendation: Failed to build quarku
s application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException:
 Unable to load the datasource driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver for the default datasource
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.validateBuildTimeConfig(AgroalProcessor.java:134)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.build(AgroalProcessor.java:94)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:820)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:455)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:405)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:455)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:405)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.validateBuildTimeConfig(AgroalProcessor.java:132)
[ERROR]         ... 12 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here are my application properties:

```
open-weather-map/mp-rest/url=https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5
open-weather-map/mp-rest/scope=javax.inject.Singleton


# Hibernate
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-schema=dbo
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-catalog=tempdb
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.globally-quoted-identifiers=true

# Datasource
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mssql
quarkus.datasource.username=sa
quarkus.datasource.password=weatherRecommendation@2021
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:57332;DatabaseName=tempdb
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=1
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=5
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.background-validation-interval=60s
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.leak-detection-interval=60s
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.idle-removal-interval=3M
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-lifetime=5M
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.new-connection-sql=select 1
```

And the pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.weather.music.recommendation</groupId>
  <artifactId>weather-music-recommendation</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.1.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    <version.mssql-jdbc>8.4.0.jre11</version.mssql-jdbc>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${version.mssql-jdbc}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to also load the database driver as dependency in the `pom.xml`. For MS SQL, we would add the following to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mssql</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

See [the official quarkus guide on panache, Section "*Setting up REST Data with Panache*](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-data-panache#setting-up-rest-data-with-panache) for details.

For a list of available driver see [the official quarkus guide on Hibernate, Section "*Setting up and configuring Hibernate ORM*"](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-data-panache#setting-up-rest-data-with-panache).

Comment: Nice, now it's working. Thanks. But i have the following issue: if i add the dependency manually in `pom.xml` it is not being recognized. 

It just worked after i do `./mvnw quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions="jdbc-mssql"`. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you - by any chance - add it to the `<dependencyManangement><dependencies>...</dependencies></dependencyManagement>`-section instead of the `<dependencies>...</dependencies>`-section?